# Python-for-android error: local variable 'targets' referenced before assignment

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, kivy

I keep getting an error when trying to create an apk with python-for-android. When I run this:

```
p4a apk --debug --sdk_dir=sdk --ndk_dir=ndk --ndk_version=r16b  --private mnt/c/main.py --package=helloworld --name "Hello World" --version 0.1 --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python2,kivy --arch=armeabi-v7a
```

I get the following error:

```
[INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    Found Android API target in $ANDROIDAPI
[ERROR]:   Could not find `android` or `sdkmanager` binaries in Android SDK. Exiting.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/p4a", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 975, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 512, in __init__
    getattr(self, args.subparser_name.replace('-', '_'))(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 144, in wrapper_func
    user_ndk_ver=self.ndk_version)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 238, in prepare_build_environment
    apis = [s for s in targets if re.match(r'^ *API level: ', s)]
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'targets' referenced before assignment
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. Here is my .bashrc file (scroll to bottom to see my additions):

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
        # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
        # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
        # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
        color_prompt=yes
    else
        color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''
s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

export ANDROIDSDK="~/sdk"
export ANDROIDNDK="~/ndk"
export ANDROIDAPI="19"
export ANDROIDNDKVER="r16b"
```

Note I downloaded the ndk from (https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html) and the sdk from (https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html). I also installed platform tools and build-tools with sdkmanager. I am a complete beginner to python-for-android, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a bug in `pythonforandroid/build.py`. Can you verify that you have the mist recent version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is pretty straightforward, you have a problem with SDK:

> [ERROR]:   Could not find `android` or `sdkmanager` binaries in
>   Android SDK. Exiting.

I'm not sure about how to make things right with Studio, but link to SDK that works:
https://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz